# Running fork(2) from Windows with Cygwin. Possible?

Tags: windows, ruby, linux, cygwin, shotgun

I am trying to use a Ruby gem called shotgun that requires fork(2) command which I discovered is aa Linux command, and might be available in Cygwin. Is it possible to make it available through Windows command shell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`fork(2)` is kludgey under Cygwin, as the Windows process model does not easily allow it to happen.  Cygwin may allow its spawn to use it, but you're going to suffer a serious performance hit as Cygwin has to emulate everything by hand -- including copying the executable data, copying the open handles, etc.

Depending on how much shotgun uses `fork(2)`, this emulation could be painful or it could be relatively minor.

Here's a [good thread on GameDev.net](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=360290) discussing the lack of a `fork` facility on Win32. They bring up something which I don't have the patience or platform accessibility to investigate, but certainly sounds fun, dangerous, and explosive all at the same time:

> So, you need to bypass Win32 and call the native API ({Nt|Zw}CreateProcess). The book "Windows Nt/2000 Native Api Reference" has an example "Forking a Win32 Process". This may be what you need.

I'm intrigued, but I doubt Cygwin uses it. It's probably there, to reiterate my answer to your question -- a lot of Unix apps rely on `fork`, and Cygwin likely makes it available. Just don't expect miracles, and you'll have to make Ruby aware of Cygwin by recompiling it to include its emulation layer.

Comment: Great reply! I will try recompiling Ruby with the Cygwin emulation layer tomorrow. If it works, that would be awesome; some performance hit would be ok. The other path sounds risky, and it would require lots of hacking...but it's good to know what's possible. Many thanks!