# shotgun gem explodes when starting a Sinatra app on windows

Tags: windows, ruby, sinatra, shotgun

Sinatra app:

```
require "rubygems"
require "sinatra"

get '/' do 
    "Hello world. It's #{Time.now} at the server!"
end
```

windows XP with latest version of mongrel, sinatra, shotgun. ruby 1.8.6

running shotgun test_app.rb results in

---

```
C:\Files\sites\sinatra>shotgun test.rb
== Shotgun starting Rack::Handler::Mongrel on localhost:9393
Thu Dec 03 16:51:37 -0800 2009: Read error: #<NotImplementedError: fork() functi
on is unimplemented on this machine>
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/shotgun-0.4/lib/shotgun.rb:26:in `fork'
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/shotgun-0.4/lib/shotgun.rb:26:in `call!'
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/shotgun-0.4/lib/shotgun.rb:15:in `call'
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/chunked.rb:15:in `call'
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/handler/mongrel.rb:61:in `process'
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/mongrel.rb:159:in `process_client'
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `each'
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `process_client'
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `initialize'
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `new'
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `initialize'
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `new'
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `run'
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/handler/mongrel.rb:34:in `run'
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/shotgun-0.4/bin/shotgun:129
c:/Ruby/bin/shotgun:19:in `load'
c:/Ruby/bin/shotgun:19
```

Any idea on how to resolve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best I can do is point you to [another thread about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814903/running-fork2-from-windows-with-cygwin-possible). Shotgun requires fork which is only available on *nix systems. There's even a bit about how to do it natively if you feel like submitting a patch.

Comment: Thank you. "You can't" is a common answer for anything Ruby related on windows :)

Comment: Haha, yeah. It's an unfortunate fact that almost all Rubyists are Mac guys. It's partly because Ruby was used only on little haughty design firms for a long time so that's where the learning-earning is. But I hear it's getting better every day!

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to go is to use *sinatra/reloader*. Install the [sinatra/contrib](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra-contrib/) gem and add the extension to your main file:

```
require 'sinatra/reloader'
```

Works fine under WIndows 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [restart gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/restart) - it was intended to be used on Windows, so it does not use `fork()`. In your example, you would simply replace **shotgun** with **restart ruby**, like this:

```
restart ruby test_app.rb
```

See [here](https://github.com/vais/restart) for more info - hope this works for you :)

Comment: Thank you for replying, I will look into it. Since I have moved to developing in an Ubuntu VM on my Windows workstation.