# Is it possible to run a thread as a process?

Tags: c++, windows

In my windows based c++ application to imports, multiple threads are created.
My application does not thread safe and not even synchronized.
So is it possible to run the thread as a process?

Comment: What would that achieve? Cross-process synchronization is even more difficult.

Comment: as per my requirement, I don't have to share the data between these 2 processes. I am working on a POC to see how feasible is that?

Comment: If you already have problems because of unsynchronized threads, you will instead have problems because of unsynchronized processes. If you don't have problems and the threads do not have to be synchronized to begin with, and you want to have several processes for simplicity and stability, e.g. so that the OS can kill some of your processes when appropriate, then okay, [do that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2618285/11683).

Comment: Thanks a ton, will try that.

Answer (score 0):

A process can be thought of as a container for threads (sometimes single-threaded though). The platform already handles it for you.

You asked:

> So is it possible to run the thread as a process?

Not directly or without some work involved. But what difference does it make to you if you run one process with a bunch of threads or multiple processes with one threads.

Comment: I am working on a POC for my project to find out all these issues. That's why I am looking for this solution.